# Switch back to IDE from RAID

Tags: windows-7, raid

I have a RAID configuration on a P8Z68-V LX motherboard.  I want to convert back to IDE mode. Will a Windows-7 system image work as a restore when I go back to IDE mode?  Or does this system image created on RAID only work to a RAID restore.

Otherwise, what is necessary to convert from 2-drive RAID 1 back to a 1-drive IDE system?

Answer (score 0):

A Windows 7 system image would not be impacted by the distinction between a RAID array and non array setup (IDE is not the proper term btw). If you make a backup or system image it should be safe to restore that back onto a non-RAID array setup.

To clarify:

[IDE is commonly misconstrued as the term](http://www.techterms.com/definition/ide) which actually refers to ATA, the connection method used for HDDs and optical drives. If you'll note SATA is similar to ATA, as it builds on the ATA and SCSI technology. IDE is more of a concept of internal devices than a connection method.

RAID arrays are simply a method of organizing HDDs. It would be proper to call a drive not in a RAID array an individual drive, there is no technical term for it that I know of as the distinction isn't exactly defined by specifications or any sort of thing.

Comment: You better inform the bios builders, they have been using ide mode in bios's for years! I prefer Pata and Sata.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the engineers know what the terminology is, I suspect it was a marketting decision to use a term which would be more distinctly recognizable to represent a legacy mode.

Comment: I get it, its wrong but widely accepted as correct.

Comment: Not sure I agree with your answer that a restore onto non-RAID will work. Windows 7 will install AHCI (incl RAID) or IDE drivers based on your bios selection. If you change the bios from one to the other the PC won't boot - Windows won't automatically detect the change and install appropriate drivers.

Comment: The RAID and AHCI drivers are the same in terms of most controllers. As long as you maintain the controller in AHCI mode this should still be fine. I have yet to see a situation where RAID was enabled but AHCI was not, such drivers should serve dual purpose.

Comment: I agree but the OP suggested converting to IDE mode which may prove a problem.

Comment: @BJ292 As I outlined IDE is not the proper term, ATA is, or in the mannor you are referring "legacy" mode for the controller. Considering that the user is not using the term properly they probably do not know the distinction between "IDE" and AHCI. As such I am trying to outline that running in AHCI mode will not only be more likely to work (as the RAID drivers probably require AHCI enabled), but also that the system will perform better if AHCI is functional.

Comment: Still agree but I have a similar mobo which can be set to RAID, AHCI or IDE - and I know from experience you cannot switch from AHCI to IDE and expect the PC to boot.

Comment: Ok. I don't want ahci or raid mode I want ide mode.  But it sounds like a systgem image from a raid mode won't boot in ide mode.  I am well aware that you can't go from ide to raid with a system imavge.  So the question remains: how to go crom raid to ide?

Comment: @BJ292 I'm not proposing that though.

Comment: @raiduser why do you not want AHCI? your system will ALWAYS perform better in AHCI mode

Comment: If it's on AHCI that certainly where I would leave it but it's not that big an improvement - it uses the same hardware - provides NCQ & hot plug and play. Benchmarks look good but in normal use not much difference. As we move to bigger disks 3TB+ and SATA 3 it will probably come into its own. On my system my secondary HD will not resume from sleep properly in AHCI mode.

Comment: @BJ292 NCQ alone warrants AHCI, when you're loading complex programs or playing games it makes the difference.